# Finding value based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can someone help me, I'm trying to find the value for ColE if is an "Individual", "Company" or "Mix" based on ColB if it has a "Y" flag.

Policy_1 only has a single row and the value for B2 is blank, is an Individual in ColE.

Policy_2 only has a single row and the value for B3 has "Y" flag, it is Company in ColE.

Policy_4 has two rows, B6 has "Y" flag and B7 is blank, it is Mix in ColE

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Excel-365 can try-

```
=IF(COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$7,$A$2:$A$7=A2)))>1,"Mix",IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,A2,$B$2:$B$7,"Y")>=1,"Company","Individual"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, the formula works great.

Answer (score 0):

Just happened to stumble on here. I think what you are looking for are the Inline IF Logical operators, and you can nest them. Like this:

**Logical IF:**

=IF(B3 = "Y",E3, "Not found!")

**Logical IF, Nested:**

=IF(B3="Y",( IF(D3="Carter", E3="This is for Carter only!", E3) ),"Not found")

***Here is how you get the Row Number for a given cell:***

**ROW()** for current cell ROW() is used in.

**So then you can use it like this:**

=IF("B" & ROW()="Y","Is a Y!!! here is the value! & "E" & ROW(), "(not a Y!!)")

***Hope this helps!***